# Migration from Gradle 5.0 to 7.0

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Here's a little piece of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5' 
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') 
}
task printDependencies {
    doLast {
        configurations.compile.each { println it.name } 
        }    
    }
```

how should the line "configurations.compile.each { println it.name }" be written in a task to make it work in Gradle 7?

I couldn't find the syntax to replace this line in the documentation (Gradle), I must have looked in the wrong place (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ConfigurationContainer doesn't have a property compile, see [Gradle API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer.html). Remove the compile and just call the following:

```
configurations.each { println it.name }
```

Comment: I would love to, but ...
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."
((

Comment: @Youstas. from what I read in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that is correct for upvotes, but I thought that you could at least accept without any other privilege than being the one who has asked in the first place.